# Iterating Over 2 Arrays And Building A New Array From Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I have an array of 'winner ids' this array represents users who have won in the previous round of a tournament. I then have an array of objects called 'tournament participations', this represents all the users that have participated in the tournament (many to many relationship join table).

For each 'winner id' I want to iterate through the 'tournament participations' array and find the tournament participation with a user_id that matches the 'winner id', then push it into a new array called 'round participations'...

I have tried the code below but I always get returned the original 'winner_ids' array....

```
@challenges = Challenge.where(tournament_id: @tournament.id)
@winner_ids = @challenges.pluck(:winner_id)
@tournament_participations = @tournament.tournament_participations
@round_participations = []
@round_participations = @winner_ids.each do |winner_id|
   @round_participation = @tournament_participations.where(user_id: winner_id)
   @round_participations << @round_participation
end
```

Comment: Try to remove assignment `@round_participations = @winner_ids.each`.

Comment: I would look for a solution where you use the database to fetch the correct records instead of pulling everything out and doing it in ruby which will not scale at all. If you give us an example of the schema and the data and the desired output we can give you a better answer than fixing your flawed attempt.

Comment: I had obviously spent too long at the computer today... Removing the assignment to round_participation has worked and I now have an array of Tournament Participation objects thanks Bruno below! @max I was under the impression the fewer calls to the database the better therefore you are best pulling data in one call and working with it in Ruby hence the methodology. I have also been recently trying to improve speed further with use of methods like .pluck (used above) to try and only work with the attributes you need... If this is not the case then we could look at another way.

Comment: Limiting the number of database calls is in general a good way to improve performance. But pulling all the records out of the database will exhaust the memory in your (application) server and cause it to crash if you have a non-trivial amount of data. Additionally databases are really good at sorting, joining and doing these kind of things really fast while pulling everything out and then doing it in Ruby is quite slow. So your conclusion is not correct.

Comment: Additionally this code actually is a really good example of a N+1 query. `@tournament_participations.where(user_id: winner_id)` will cause an additional round trip to the database for every iteration. What you should be doing instead is a single database query that joins the relevant tables which you can most likely do by just setting up your associations correctly. This quite a bit more important then using `pluck` to just select the columns you want which is like putting makeup on a pig.

Comment: Thanks max, would you be interested in looking at the code in my project and running through areas for improvement on speed? I know outside the scope of this site but happy to do something through flattr or something? Whats the best way to contact?

Comment: Also the @tournament_participations.where(user_id: winner_id) is outside the iteration and is only called once at the top to return an array of Challenges for the Tournament's previous round so I can extract the winner ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each` returns the enumerable it was called on; in this case, `@winner_ids.each` is returning `@winner.ids`. You don't need to assign the result of the iteration to `@round_participations`.

Also, check out [the `map` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-map).

Answer (score 1):

Use the map method, instead of .each.

The map method can be used to create a new array based on the original array, but with the values modified by the supplied block. See the below example.

In case of **each** method

```
irb(main):001:0> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> arr.each { |a| print a -= 10, " " }
-9 -8 -7 -6 -5 
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

you can see after iterations it returned the original array. But in the case of **map**

```
irb(main):005:0> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):006:0> arr.map { |a| 2*a }
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

**map** can transform the contents of an array, meaning that it can perform an operation on each element in the array.

Comment: Thanks sk1712! Getting rid of the assignment worked but could also have used .map :)